# delayWhen is deprecated RxJs

Tags: intellij-idea, rxjs, deprecated

I got a `Deprecated symbol used ...` warning inside my IDE for using `delayWhen` in my app.

[image]

**My code:**

```
private nextImg(): Observable<void> {
    return this.stream$.pipe(
          delayWhen(() => timer(1000),
          tap(() => this.subject.next(NEXT_IMG)),
         );
}
```

I've checked the [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/delayWhen.ts) of the `delayWhen` operator and the [docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/delayWhen) as well, but I can't find what to use instead of `delayWhen`. Any idea?

Comment: Why use `delayWhen(() => timer(1000)` here? You can simply use `delay(1000)` instead. Check for more information [the documenation on delay here](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/delay).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `delayWhen` operator isn't deprecated, only the function overload is marked as deprecated.

> @deprecated In future versions, empty notifiers will no longer re-emit the source value on the output observable.

So your IDE mistakenly marks the hole operator as deprecated.

Comment: This seems to be the case for IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3

Comment: is there any workaround such as typing the function in the meantime ?

Comment: This is still the case in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1

Answer (score -2):

You're missing a closing paren in:

```
delayWhen(() => timer(1000),
```

Should be:

```
delayWhen(() => timer(1000)),
```