# Asynchronous equivalent to tap() in RxJS?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have a side effect Observable that's required to be resolved before the main Observable is completed. If it were a synchronous operation, I could use the `tap()` operator. Is there a clear equivalent for an asynchronous operation?

In the following example, I have to map the inner value back to the outer value I actually want to pipe through. How would I avoid this mapping?

```
  const user = requestUser().pipe( 
    switchMap(user => {
      return requestAndAssignToken(user)
        .pipe(
          map(token => user)
        );
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to ignore the result of the inner Observable and just have the outer Observable wait for it to emit before moving on.

In that case, I'd suggest the `delayWhen` operator. It is passed a `delayDurationSelector` that returns an Observable (the `duration Observable`). It then behaves like [stated in the documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/delayWhen):

> The source value is emitted on the output Observable only when the duration Observable emits a value or completes

For your example, it would look like this:

```
const user = requestUser().pipe( 
    delayWhen(user => requestAndAssignToken(user))
);
```

[Here is a simple example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-n3lqhb?devtoolsheight=60)

Comment: Hmm, without the `switchMap()`, `requestAndAssignToken()` doesn't actually run. I'm not sure how to work in that subscription.

Comment: that's odd. do you subscribe to `user` ?

Comment: Here is a simple reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-n3lqhb?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Ok, this appears to work and seems simple enough. Thanks!

Comment: `delayWhen` is: `@deprecated In future versions, empty notifiers will no longer re-emit the source value on the output observable`

Comment: @DanielKucal "The delayWhen operator isn't deprecated, only the function overload is marked as deprecated. So your IDE mistakenly marks the hole operator as deprecated." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52639489/delaywhen-is-deprecated-rxjs